# How to find the pageviews per country?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to know how to find the page views per country from Audience Section using Google Analytics.

So, for example from 1/April to 30 April I need to see table like that

```
    Country PageViews
    USA      1000
    Uk       2000

etc ...
```